# CSS left not working as expected

Tags: html, asp.net, css

I have added a video player to my asp.net website.  It consists of a video player screen and a list box that appears to the right of it that allows the user to select a video to play.

I notice that the video list does not appear in the correct position as it appears on top of the video and not the right of it.

In Visual Studio 2012 I have used Page Inspector and the left css value appears striked out like so:
[image]

The left css tag is 641 which should move it over to the right (The width of the actual video player)  so why is it not working??
Any why do the other css entries have a line through them also? (height, position etc)

**EDIT**

If I untick[image] the 'width' in 'element.style' it works as expected:

But now how do I track down where the 'element.style' is? I have searched for it but its not in my code..

The playiistHolder had the following css:

```
/* playlist holder */   
.componentWrapper .playlistHolder{
position:absolute;
top:0px;
left:641px;
width:320px;
height:100%;
background:#111;
overflow:hidden;
/*display:none;*/
}
```

Comment: The line through generally means that that style is being overridden by a higher priority one.

Comment: Thanks, how can I track down what is overriding it??

Comment: `left: 641px !important` to overwrite

Comment: If you open it on a browser, go to the console (usually F12) and then just go to the "Style" tab and track the last ocorrency with no "line" on it.

Comment: left only applies to positioned elements, do you have some sort of positioning set on it?

Comment: Thanks for the replies.  Felipe look at my edit to see what you have helped me find out.  I'm not sure how to fix this now.

Comment: @HarryBoy, You didn't find it (the css line) because those 3 lines of code were inserted by a script.

Comment: @DanielCheung I have tried inserting !important but it didn't make any difference.

Comment: Try to "ctrl+f" inside your solution something like $('.playlistHolder') or just .playlistHolder and you will find the script for sure!

Comment: @FelipeMiosso Thanks, so how can I figure out what script is doing this?

Comment: Maybe if you change the class name of the element you will get some errors. You can start from there